# Android - LinearLayout not scrolling inside ScrollVIew

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I have the problem with LinearLayout not being scrollable inside the ScrollView, instead it just appears to go beyond the screen frame (look closely at the bottom of the screenshot linked below).

I have the following structure in my XML layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <!-- More TextInputLayouts -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src = "@drawable/ic_done"
        android:tint = "@color/white"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

No solutions found were able to fix the problem: I tried fillViewPort="true" and it didn't do it for me, I also tried commenting CoordinatorLayout - same result, layout_heights seem to be set properly as well.

Moreover, I tried to adjust LinearLayout's height progrmatically, what didn't help just as well.

I'm stuck with this problem for a while now and would really appreciate any help in this regard :)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpRht.jpg)

Comment: Try using `wrap_content` instead on your ScrollView, there might even be a warning saying that already.

Comment: Did you try adding `android:fillViewport="true"` inside the ScrollView within the xml layout?

Comment: @Nicolas did not work

Comment: @bko ScrollView changes so it is no longer coming off the screen at the bottom, however the LinearLayout inside is still not scrollable

Comment: @IliaGromov try setting the height of the linear layout to match parent also...

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with the XML below. I didn't change much, just added an orientation to the LinearLayout and some margin and awful background colors so you can see which view is moving and which is fixed while you scroll.

When you drag up and down, the teal box (the LinearLayout) moves up and down as expected within the red box (the ScrollView). If your LinearLayout is taller than the screen, it will go off the bottom, that's the point of the ScrollView.

[image: Scollbar screenshot]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="#008080"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you put linear layout orientation in xml code
like..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>
```

or

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/whiteColor"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">
<!-- vertical ScrollView to make all the items or views scrollable -->
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="none">
 <!-- LinearLayout Inside ScrollView -->
 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- create a Linear Layout with horizontal orientation and weightSum property -->
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:weightSum="2">
 <EditText
 android:id="@+id/lastName"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_weight="1.4"
 android:background="@color/editTextBack"
 android:hint="Last Name"
 android:imeOptions="actionNext"
 android:paddingLeft="10dp"
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:textColor="@color/blackColor" />
 </LinearLayout>
 <!-- create a Linear Layout with horizontal orientation and weightSum property -->

 <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/thirdLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <!-- place one TextView and one EditText inside layout using weight property -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Address"
            android:textColor="@color/blackColor" />


 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```